# Template instead of macro as class field

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm trying to `modernize` my code with the help of some clang-tidy suggestions. Say I have a class like this:

```
class Config {
public:
  static constexpr auto FIELD1 = "FIELD1";
  static constexpr auto FIELD2 = "FIELD2";  
};
```

Since the list of fields grows bigger, I have a simple macro:

```
#define CONFIG_PARAM(param) \
  static constexpr auto param = #param;
```

which can transform my code into less boilerplate-ish version:

```
class Config {
public:
  CONFIG_PARAM(FIELD1)
  CONFIG_PARAM(FIELD2)
};
```

And it works just fine. Except that I get a warning from clang-tidy saying I should consider a constexpr template function for this purpose. Is there an arcane feature I am not aware of that could create member variables like this out of a template?

Comment: Can you provide the message from `clang-tidy`?

Comment: IMHO it's cleaner without the macro (especially if it's in a header file)

Comment: The way you are doing it is just fine. Don't fix what isn't broken, and don't make things more complicated then they need to be.

Comment: @Quimby `Function-like macro 'CONFIG_PARAM' used; consider a 'constexpr' template function [clang-tidy: cppcoreguidelines-macro-usage] `

Comment: @StefanRiedel EmanuelP Sure, it's kind of over-engineering at this point but I consider it a mildly interesting code puzzle.

Comment: Looks like clang-tidy is a bit optimistic about this situation - you can't stringify an identifier without using macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it is suggesting is this:

```
template <T> constexpr T* config_param(const T* v) {
    return v;
}

class Config {
public:
    auto FIELD1 = config_param("FIELD1");
}
```

I would ignore it, and leave it like it is.

Comment: Ah, so there's no hidden gem then to make my code even more unreadable. What a letdown! I guess I'll stick with `// NOLINTNEXTLINE(cppcoreguidelines-macro-usage)` then. Thanks.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs It can be useful in cases where you needed to do maths with the preprocessor, which you can now do with a constexpr function. It's just not smart enough to see when it's useful and when it isn't.